# Java: How to count and process elements in a Stream without auxiliary structures or peek()?

Tags: java, java-stream, peek

I'm working with Java streams and I need a method to both count all elements in the stream and, at the same time, perform operations on a subset of them using `skip()` and `limit()`.
I'm aiming to do this without using any auxiliary structures to reduce heap space usage, because the data entered can be very large.

I'd also prefer to steer clear of the `peek()` method due to its potential side effects in specific scenarios, as detailed in this [4Comprehension article](https://4comprehension.com/idiomatic-peeking/).

```
public static <T> long extractAndProcess(Stream<T> streamData, int pageIndex, int itemsPerPage,   Consumer<T> itemHandler) {

    long startPosition = (long) pageIndex * itemsPerPage;
    AtomicLong totalCount = new AtomicLong();

    streamData.peek(item -> totalCount.incrementAndGet())
              .skip(startPosition)
              .limit(itemsPerPage)
              .forEachOrdered(itemHandler);

    return totalCount.get();
}
```

I tried to use `peek()` here, but in combination with `.limit()` it doesn't work as I assumed in the specific cases.

Comment: You're trying to do paging and get the max count at the same time. But you're trying to do it in a real silly way (especially if you're retrieving all data just to get the max count). Where does the stream originate from? Why don't you do the limit/offset in the original datasource, so it'll be more efficient.

Comment: I understand your concerns. However, the solution I've presented is due to the requirements of a legacy code structure I have to work with. I'm trying to find the most efficient way to operate within these constraints. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only viable solution that deals with the case you've described looks like

```
streamData.forEachOrdered(elem -> {
  int i = totalCount.getAndIncrement();
  if (i >= startPosition && i < startPosition + itemsPerPage) {
    itemHandler.accept(i);
  }
})
```

I don't believe a better solution exists; streams are really not designed to do what you're trying to do with them.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, this approach increments the counter only for elements after the skip() and limit() operations. I need to count all the items in the stream before applying those operations. It's a very specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using the [JEP 461: Stream Gatherers](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461) Java 22 preview language feature.  As it's a preview feature of an upcoming Java release, it's not yet something that's ready for production code.

```java
public static <T> long extractAndProcess(
        Stream<T> streamData, int pageIndex, int itemsPerPage, Consumer<T> itemHandler) {
    class Count {
        long count = 0;
    }

    long startPosition = (long) pageIndex * itemsPerPage;
    long endPosition = startPosition + itemsPerPage;

    return streamData
            .gather(Gatherer.<T, Count, Long>ofSequential(
                    Count::new,
                    Gatherer.Integrator.ofGreedy((state, element, downstream) -> {
                        long count = state.count++;
                        if (startPosition <= count && count < endPosition) {
                            itemHandler.accept(element);
                        }
                        return true;
                    }),
                    (state, downstream) -> downstream.push(state.count)))
            .findAny().orElseThrow();
}
```

This uses the new [`Stream.gather`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)) method with a custom [`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html) which counts all the elements in the stream, and applies the given `itemHandler` in order to any elements within the given page.  The results of this `gather` method is a `Stream<Long>` with a single element equal to the count of items in the stream.

Internally, the count is captured in a single interim `Count` object, and its `long` count value is returned by the gatherer's finisher.

## Javadocs

[`Gatherer`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html):

> An intermediate operation that transforms a stream of input elements into a stream of output elements, optionally applying a final action when the end of the upstream is reached. […]
>
> […]
>
> There are many examples of gathering operations, including but not limited to: grouping elements into batches (windowing functions); de-duplicating consecutively similar elements; incremental accumulation functions (prefix scan); incremental reordering functions, etc. The class [`Gatherers`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherers.html) provides implementations of common gathering operations.
>
> **API Note:**
>
> A `Gatherer` is specified by four functions that work together to process input elements, optionally using intermediate state, and optionally perform a final action at the end of input. They are:
>
> - creating a new, potentially mutable, state ([`initializer()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#initializer()))
> - integrating a new input element ([`integrator()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#integrator()))
> - combining two states into one ([`combiner()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#combiner()))
> - performing an optional final action ([`finisher()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#finisher()))

[`Stream.gather(Gatherer<? super T,?,R> gatherer)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#gather(java.util.stream.Gatherer)):

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given gatherer to the elements of this stream.

[`Gatherer.ofSequential(initializer, integrator, finisher)`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Gatherer.html#ofSequential(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.stream.Gatherer.Integrator,java.util.function.BiConsumer))

> Returns a new, sequential, `Gatherer` described by the given  `initializer`, `integrator`, and `finisher`.